# Having problem to setup raspberry pi

Tags: setup

I'm having a MacBook to setup my raspberry pi. I have my SD card with Raspbian and my Raspberry pi connected through ethernet cable. The light on the board lit perfectly, but I have a hard time completing the setup. When I typed `ping raspberrypi.local` in my terminal window, it always shows `ping: cannot resolve raspberrypi.local: Unknown host`
. 
[image]
By the way, I already had my MacBook sharing through ethernet cable.

Here is more detail:
 After installing Raspbian on my SD card, I created a ssh file in the SD card. I then plugged in my SD card into my raspberry pi and had my raspberry pi connected with my macbook through ethernet cable. I could see "Thunderbolt Ethernet and self-assigned IP address" from the network preference. I tried to find the real IP address of my raspberry pi. I typed `ping` or `nmap`, but none of those work. Here is the result:
[image]
I follow steps given by these materials but it always ends up the same way.

https://medium.com/@viveks3th/how-to-bootstrap-a-headless-raspberry-pi-with-a-mac-6eba3be20b26

https://youtu.be/-v88m-HYeys

I even tried to shut down my firewall, but I still can't see the host from my raspberry pi.

Comment: Computers don't magically know which name another computer on the network has. You have to check you DHCP server (usually inside your internet router) which name it assigned to the Raspberry Pi when it was asking for one.

Comment: @Janka I think Raspbian by default runs `avahi`, which includes [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS); other systems commonly also use this.

Comment: Simon, you need to explain in more detail what the scenario is.  You say, *"I already had my MacBook sharing through ethernet cable"*, presumably to the Pi.  How did you set this up?

Comment: @Janka said, "Computers don't magically know which name another computer on the network has."  Actually they do... [Zero Configuration Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) has made this a reality. And Apple's "Bonjour" is an implementation of ZCN.

Comment: If it would only work reliably. (maybe in an Apple-only environment, it does.)